# Errors with operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i have two different operator overloading. For some reason it is giving error.
If i remove one of it,  than it does not show any error. May i know why ?

Can i combine both ?

This is used for printing on screen.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Point &p) {
return out << "[" << setw(4) << p.getX() << setw(1) << "," << setw(4) << p.getY() << "]   " << setprecision(3) << p.getScalarValue() << endl;
}
```

This is used for printing on a text file.

```
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream &out, const Point2D &p){
return out << "[" << setw(4) << p.getX() << setw(1) << "," << setw(4) << p.getY() << "]   " << setprecision(3) << p.getScalarValue() << endl;
}
```

Error:

> Point.cpp:91:147: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::ofstream& {aka std::basic_ofstream&}’ from expression of type ‘std::basic_ostream::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream}’

Comment: You wrote `ofstream` instead of `ostream` in the second definition.

Comment: Are you trying to write an `ofstream` version, a `Point2D` version, or both?

Comment: You will receive better answers quicker if you provide a minimal, complete sample program with your questions. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Comment: @juanchopanza I need to overload and << operator that can write on the standard screen and also into a file when it is used. So i thought ostream is used for standard output and ofstream is used for writing into files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the second version. You can use the first:

```
Point p;
std::ofstream pointsFile("points.txt");
pointsFile << p << "\n";
```

First, The `std::ostream& operator<<` works for writing to files as well as writing to the standard output or stderrt

Second, assuming `Poind2D` inherits from `Point`, passing a `Point2D` to a function or operator that takes a `Point` reference will work too.

Comment: the second argument are not of the same type.

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It I cannot figure out what OP is asking exactly.

Comment: @juanchopanza so i dont need to declare seprately ?

Comment: @user1571494 exactly, you only need the `ostream` version.